# Как выделить весь текст формы при клике на нее?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как выделить весь текст формы при клике на нее?

Comment: выделить визуально(цветом, размером, бордером,...) или выделить текст как ctrl+a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
​$( function(){
    $('input').click( function(){
        $(this).select()
    })
})
```

Comment: вместо $(this).select() лучше использовать this.select() экономия же на лицо.

Comment: о да XD...

Comment: самый экономный вариант (если используется одна форма) <input onclick="this.select()">

Comment: тесты: http://jsperf.com/selecttest123/3  Как видно разница между $(this) и this минимальна. А вариант @Ъь_ жжот =)

Comment: @Яковлев Андрей всё равно на каждый клик создается объект jQuery.